# flutter - bad perf- advice

Tags: performance, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm developing my first app with flutter. At some point I was wondering :Am I developping the UX part correctly ? Meaning am I using the proper widget, is there any better way to do that etc.. I find out about Flutter Performance on Intellj Idea and I saw that most of the pages I developed are red...

FYI : The code I created for a simple page

Flutter inspector result => [radio-btn-aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAIhF.png)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:testapp/my_theme.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: MyAppTheme(ctx: context).defaultTheme,
      home: new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text("Title"),
          ),
          body: AddDailyTaskPage()),
    );
  }
}

enum Options { goal, category }

class AddDailyTaskPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddDailyTaskPageState createState() => new _AddDailyTaskPageState();
}

class _AddDailyTaskPageState extends State<AddDailyTaskPage> {
  Options _options = Options.goal;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            child: Text("Task Description"),
          ),
          Container(child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Radio<Options>(
                      value: Options.goal,
                      groupValue: _options,
                      onChanged: (Options value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _options = value;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                   Text(
                      'Goal',
                      style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                    )
                  ]
                )
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      child: Radio(
                        value: Options.category,
                        groupValue: _options,
                        onChanged: (Options value) {
                          setState(() {
                            _options = value;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: Text(
                        'Category',
                        style: new TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                )
              )
            ],
          ),)
          // Container(
          //   child: TextField(
          //     maxLines: 10,
          //     decoration: InputDecoration(
          //       // suffixIcon:
          //       focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          //         borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 5.0),
          //       ),
          //       enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          //         borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 5.0),
          //       ),
          //       hintText: 'Description task',
          //     ),
          //   ),
          // )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

To see the difference, I checked the sample code provided while creating a flutter Project

FYI :
flutter performance result : [auto-increment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jk3Rj.png)
As we can see on the previous pic, it doesn't seems optimised.. :/

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Few questions :
1/ Does anyone has / knows a good flutter repo with ton of examples based on performance ?

2/ What is your standard in term of perf ? I mean on my virtual device, the UX seems fluid but if the Flutter Perf is "red", then I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong and there is a better way to do ?

3/ Do you guys knows a website / forum / someone who's willing to do a core review once a week to help me implementing good pattern in my flutter application ?

4/ What is wrong with my current design ? What is wrong with the default design ? Why the performance are doesn't seems good ? I started to read the official documentation for the perf, but how could I know if the UX itself have good perf or not ? Actually by testing some stuff, I find out that putting everything in Container / Row or Column widget, improved a lot the performance but even with this widgets, it's not enough :/

Any advice ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: If you're measuring performance, [always use a real device and build your app in release or profile mode](https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/rendering/ui-performance#connect-to-a-physical-device).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a StatefulWidget for the whole page. That means that when you call setState() the whole page gets rebuild.

One example is:

```
Radio<Options>(
  value: Options.goal,
  groupValue: _options,
  onChanged: (Options value) {
    setState(() {
      _options = value;
    });
  },
),
```

There's no need to rebuild your whole page when you set an option. If you extract that code out into it's own StatefulWidget, only this portion gets rebuild.

You can click on "Track Widget rebuilds" to see what Widgets do rebuild in your app and then think about whether those Widget actually should rebuild.

Once you do smaller Widgets you get the problem that events in one Widget are supposed to influence other Widgets. That's when state management solutions come into play. The [weather example](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterweathertutorial) of the Bloc package shows a good structure of an app that you can copy.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! In one sentence you made me understand a lot more about Flutter : `That means that when you call setState() the whole page gets rebuild.` Thanks a lot